# Deleting with 3 verifiers

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to delete something with 3 verification checks.  how can i do it.  Currently this is the way i am doing it:

```
 mysql_query("DELETE FROM comments WHERE comment_id='$comment' AND (
 p_id='$pid'
 for_w = '$z'");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about:

```
"DELETE FROM comments WHERE comment_id='$comment' AND p_id='$pid' AND for_w = '$z'"
```

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there:

```
 mysql_query("DELETE FROM comments WHERE comment_id='$comment' 
                                   AND p_id='$pid' 
                                   AND for_w = '$z'");
```

Answer (score 1):

1 - You have to put AND between your second and third condition
2 - Remove ( after the first one:

```
mysql_query("DELETE FROM comments WHERE comment_id='$comment' AND
 p_id='$pid' AND
 for_w = '$z'");
```